# MVC crazy property lose its value. Does Html.HiddenFor bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There something really weird happening in my MVC application that drives me crazy.
On my MVC Page, after a user got selected, it's Login should be "rendered" twice on the HTML.
Once in the form of

```
FrmNextStep('<Login>', ...
(where Model.SelectedUser.Login is used)
```

and once in the form of

```
<input id="SelectedLogin" name="SelectedLogin" value="<Login>" type="hidden">
(where "Model".SelectedLogin is used)
```

but the second one always stay blank.
It's really weird because, despite the two call not being exactly the same, the return value should be.

```
if (Model.SelectedUser != null)
{
    <span>Some value</span>
    <script type="scriptADResultComplete">
    @{
        var script = String.Format(
            @"FrmNextStep('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');"
            , Model.SelectedUser.Login.Replace("'", @"\'")
            , Model.SelectedUser.FirstName.Replace("'", @"\'")
            , Model.SelectedUser.LastName.Replace("'", @"\'")
        );

        @Html.Raw(script);
    }
    </script>
}

<input type="hidden" name="hfAction" />
<input type="hidden" name="hfUserLogin" />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentPage, new { id = "hfCurrentPage" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedLogin);


    private User selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.selectedUser == null)
            {
                this.selectedUser = this.AllUsers.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Selected) ?? User.DefaultUser;
            }

            if (this.selectedUser == User.DefaultUser)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return this.selectedUser;
        }
        set
        {
            this.AllUsers.ForEach(user => user.Selected = (user == value));

            this.selectedUser = null;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedLogin
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.SelectedUser ?? User.DefaultUser).Login;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SelectedUser = this.AllUsers.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Login == value);
        }
    }
```

And when I have debug the code,the only call to Selected Login during the "rendering" phase and return the correct login.

Is there any bug with Html.HiddenFor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, it's actually a bug/faulty behaviour of Html.HiddenFor.

The idea of this possibility only came to my mind while I was writing my question.

I changed it into:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.SelectedLogin)" id="SelectedLogin" name="SelectedLogin" />
```

and it's working perfectly fine.

EDIT:

There's another workarround.

Call ModelState.Clear(); in the controler post action.

I'll use this option.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

+

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedLogin)
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the reason might be that this isn't a "bug/faulty behaviour of Html.HiddenFor". If using `ModelState.Clear()` works, it seems likely (can't tell from your code) that there's a `SelectedLogin` property in your `ModelState` (e.g. a value POSTed to the controller action), which is different from the value on your model. The HTML helpers will always choose `ModelState` over `Model` when picking the value. This is by design, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, with the .cshtml executing twice while returning the page, and the second run having issues with null model objects.

Using [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876706/serge)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816657) fixes the `HiddenFor`'s, but then I also had issues with partials that can't be solved this way.

It turns out to be an intermittent issue, where the `Controller` method that invokes the view is setting `ViewBag` properties together with returning the view+model separately via `protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, object model);`.

The project I'm working on has this all over the place, and on other controllers/views it works fine. But for the one I was maintaining, this null issue in the `HiddenFor`'s was happening.

Anyway, I pulled all the `ViewBag` setters out of the controller, and moved them into `NotMapped` properties on the model object.

Once this was done the `HiddenFor` calls etc all started behaving again. So, don't mix your ViewBag and ViewModel kids.